# Error convirtiendo imagen a base 64 en javascript react

Tags: javascript

El problema que tengo es el siguiente: Tengo una función llamada handleFile que es esta

```
handleFile(e) {
    var value = e.target.files
    var array = []
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(value[0]);
    reader.onload = () => {
        let fileInfo = {
            name: value.name,
            type: value.type,
            size: Math.round(value.size / 1000) + ' kB',
            base64: reader.result,
            file: value,
        }
        array.push(fileInfo)
    }
    console.log(array)
}
```

La función anterior se encarga de convertir una imagen a  un string   base64,
la conversión se hace de manera correcta, pero al momento de salir del contexto de esa función que se hace con onload la variable se vuelve indefinida, inluso si asigno dicha variable a otra variable, la variable a la que se la asigno se muestra de manera correcta si la imprimo en ese contexto, pero al momento en que se vuelve al punto handleFile  la variable se convierte en indefinida, he tratado de guardar esa data en el state, en arreglos, incluso retornado el valor cabe destacar que en este caso me devuelve un objeto solo con las keys del objeto, la verdad es que no soy muy versado en lo que respecta a JavaScript y React, les agradecería si me pudieran ayudar

Comment: Creo que se vuelve indefinido porq estas usando una variable let y cuando las pusheas los objetos se pasan por referencia. Intenta pusheando de esta manera: array.push({ ...fileInfo })

Comment: Ya probe y sigue igual

Comment: te sugiero revisar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47176280/how-to-convert-files-to-base64-in-react

Comment: Fue muy útil. Ya puedo resorverlo

Answer (score 1):

Intenta definir la variable de forma global y luego dentro de la función poblarla con la información:

```
const array = []; //Aquí está definida globalmente

handleFile(e) {
    var value = e.target.files        
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(value[0]);
    reader.onload = () => {
        let fileInfo = {
            name: value.name,
            type: value.type,
            size: Math.round(value.size / 1000) + ' kB',
            base64: reader.result,
            file: value,
        }
        array.push(fileInfo)
    }
    console.log(array)
}
```

Con esto ya debería dejar de ser `undefined`.